# Urban Airship device tokens remain active between installs

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

So I'm running into a peculiar problem that I have not been able to find much information on. Looking for any input or experience at all.

I have recorded the deviceToken of an existing app install using Urban Airship. Then deleting the app and reinstalling, I recorded the new device token as well. These tokens are different. From the UA test panel, I am able to send a test push to both of these tokens and the device receives 2 pushes, one for each token, even though the first token has since been uninstalled. But, in UA device lookup, both tokens are marked as active.

This was only caught after getting our push server running which triggers a push once every morning at most, based on a hosted file that determines the push contents and if one should happen. My development device is now getting up to 8 pushes at once from the server.

There are ways to unsubscribe or unregister for push notifications with Apple, UA, and the server, but I'm wondering on the best practices for this. There is no way to get the uninstall event either which would be the only time to unsubscribe. Is the best solution just to wait for UA to determine a token is inactive? I have found this list here for reasons a token could be inactive: http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/troubleshooting/ios-push.html#inactive-device-token

But none seem to apply here, especially because some of these device tokens are nearly a month old and still sending to my test device. The app uses an Enterprise profile so this is happening in a production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting the same channel every time? Usually reinstalls will generate the same channel which is tied to a single device token. Then when apple generates a new token it will update the channel's token. You are probably better off contacting support directly. They will be able to help gather all the device info they need and look up registration and push records to figure out whats going on.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the channel id is what I needed. Contacting support they said to go with the channel id as well. Due to working on an older push server, the work to convert to channel id has not been approved but I'm sure that will do the trick.